# Windows Phone 8 Silverlight dont load new images on second page

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a `windows phone 8.1 silverlight` app.

I have this problem:

When a try open a new Page using :

> NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Menu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

The page open normally, but I can't load new images, I can only use the images that I used on the `first page`.

**First page XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#f3f3f4">

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="LogoPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,120,0,28">
        <Image Height="100" Source="Assets/Logo.png"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="LogoPanel1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,400,0,28">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtUsername" Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Username" Foreground="#A7A5A8" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="txtUsername_LostFocus"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="txtPassword" Height="72" Password="password"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#A7A5A8" Width="468" Style="{StaticResource PasswordBoxStyle1}" LostFocus="txtPassword_LostFocus" GotFocus="txtPassword_GotFocus"/>
        <Button Content="LOGIN" Background="#18a689" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Second Page XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#f3f3f4">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="userPanel" Height="200" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#18a689">
        <Grid x:Name="userGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- User Image -->
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="178" Source="Assets/User.png"/>

            <!-- User Info -->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ricardo Sampaio" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="rsampaio@hydra.pt" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

CS FILE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using FlyGolf_V1.Resources;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace FlyGolf_V1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region placeholders

    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == "Username")
        {
            txtUsername.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void txtUsername_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == "")
        {
            txtUsername.Text = "Username";
        }
    }

    private void txtPassword_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPassword.Password == "password")
        {
            txtPassword.Password = "";
        }
    }

    private void txtPassword_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPassword.Password == "")
        {
            txtPassword.Password = "password";
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/Menu.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that `Assets/User.png` will load if you put it on page 1?

Comment: Put your cs file code

Comment: @smoothersillent sillent ok :)

Comment: @Agostinhob07 where is image display/binding code in your cs file ?

Comment: @smoothersillent i'm just showing the image on 
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="178" Source="Assets/User.png"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First page XAML:**

```
<Image Height="100" Source="Assets/Logo.png"/>
```

Here Image `Source="Assets/Logo.png"`

**Second Page XAML:**

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="178" Source="Assets/User.png"/>
```

Here Image `Source="Assets/User.png"`

check your `Assets folder` has `User.png` image exits.

Second Page XAML Edit:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="178" Source="/Assets/User.png"/>
```

Comment: Yes the User.png exists

If i try show it on first page i dont have problems

Comment: Check your XAML `First page` and `Second Page` path. Is it in `same folder` ?

Comment: Noup Second File is in /Views folder

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please Add / (Slash) before Assets/User.png In your XAML file

As Below..

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="178" Source="/Assets/User.png"/>
```